# Настроить VirtualHost nginx

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Настроить VirtualHost nginx почему-то не создает виртуалхост с аналогичным конфигом. Welcome to nginx! есть, а домен не хочет. брал конфиги с соседнего домена с ним все ок. Кто может помочь.

VIRTUALHOST::

```
       server
{  listen          IP:80;

    server_name     www.DOMAIN.ru DOMAIN.ru;
    root /var/www/DOMAIN/;

    include common.conf;

    access_log /var/www/DOMAIN/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/DOMAIN/logs/nginx_error.log;
}
```

NGINX CONF:::

```
include modules-enabled/*;
user  www-data www-data;
worker_processes  8;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  5;

    proxy_connect_timeout      300;
    proxy_send_timeout         300;
    proxy_read_timeout         300;
    proxy_buffer_size          64k;
    proxy_buffers              8 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;

    client_header_timeout   3m;
    client_body_timeout     3m;
    send_timeout        3m;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version               1.0;
    gzip_comp_level                 2;
    gzip_proxied                    any;
    gzip_types                      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript
                                    text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss
                                    text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml application/json;

    client_max_body_size 50m;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;


    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    include conf.d/*;
    include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: А зачем `listen IP:80` если обычно можно просто `listen 80`?

Comment: спс за замечание, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с конфигами как ни странно оказалось все ок. проблема была в том что DNS не на тот домен смотрел...